# How select join sum with 0 returned if not exist

Tags: sql-server, join, query, sum

[image]

I need some advice. I want to select join with sum.

```
select year(date), month(mon), c.id, c.name, sum(t.trx_detail)
from client c 
left join trx t 
on c.id = t.id
group by year(date), month(mon), c.id, c.name
```

That query only shows id with transaction on trx.

How I can show the result id with 0 result / no trx from all data on client?

Comment: Aggregate `trx` in subquery then LEFT JOIN it to `client`. Use COLAESCE() for to replace NULL to zero. PS. `month(mon)` is a typo, must be `month(date)`.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems to solve here, if I'm reading your desired output correctly. One is to return a zero even if there are no transactions for that client in that month. The other, less obvious one, is to get a complete list of all clients for all months even if there are no transactions for them.

I'll explain my solution in comments through the query.

I can't be bothered to type out all the sample data you give in the question so I use only a few rows. You really do need to follow mustaccio's advice for your next question. Also it's a bad idea to use reserved words like "name" and "date" for column names.

```
-- Test data.
-- A is in August only
-- B has no rows
-- C is in both July and August

create table #client
(
    client_id char(1) not null
);

insert #client(client_id)
values
    ('a'), ('b'), ('c');


create table #trx
(
    dt          date   not null,
    client_id   char(9) not null,
    trx_detail  int    not null
);

insert #trx(dt, client_id, trx_detail)
values
    ('2022-08-01', 'a', 10), ('2022-08-02', 'a', 20),
    ('2022-07-01', 'c', 10), ('2022-08-01', 'c', 30);



;with Months as
(
    -- Get a list of year/month combinations. I get this from the actual data.
    -- Note that if there is a month with no transactions there will be no rows
    -- whatsoever in the output for that month.
    -- If you have a calendar table that may be a better source. It would avoid
    -- the missed months.
    select distinct
        YEAR(dt) yr, MONTH(dt) mt
    from #trx
),
AllCombos as
(
    -- Now combine every year/month with every client. This solves the
    -- base problem. Now we have somewhere to put the zeros or totals.
    select *
    from Months
    cross join #client
)
select
    ac.yr,
    ac.mt,
    ac.client_id,
    ISNULL(SUM(t.trx_detail), 0) sum_trx
from AllCombos ac
-- Left join so all year/month/client combinations are returned,
-- even if they have no data.
left outer join #trx t
    on  YEAR(t.dt) = ac.yr
    and MONTH(t.dt) = ac.mt
    and t.client_id = ac.client_id
group by
    ac.yr,
    ac.mt,
    ac.client_id
order by
    ac.yr,
    ac.mt,
    ac.client_id;


drop table if exists #client;
drop table if exists #trx;
```

Which gives these results

```
yr          mt          client_id sum_trx
----------- ----------- --------- -----------
2022        7           a         0
2022        7           b         0
2022        7           c         10
2022        8           a         30
2022        8           b         0
2022        8           c         30
```

I've structured this as CTEs because it is easy to read when explaining what's going on. Structuring it this way does not affect performance or correctness.